# ERROR: check constraint "dates_check" is violated by some row

Tags: postgresql

`ALTER table myTable ADD CONSTRAINT dates_check CHECK(start_date::date < end_date::date);`

Gives..

> ERROR:  check constraint "dates_check" is violated by some
>   row

But..

`select start_date, end_date from myTable where start_date::date > end_date::date;`

Returns..

`start_date | end_date
------------+----------
(0 rows)`

Comment: Maybe try a `BETWEEN` query?

Comment: `start_date::date > end_date::date` is not the opposite of `start_date::date < end_date::date`

Answer (score 3):

If it is `=`, then it is neither `>` nor `<`.  It violates your constraint, but is not returned by your query.

Comment: This. You have at least one row with `start_date::date = end_date::date`.